# Split message and promote properties via Biztalk pipeline

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am polling a well formatted xml messages from SQL Server table using sqlserver stored procedure that returnes me xml like the following one

```
<PolledMessage xmlns="http://SomeNamespace.ru/">
  <Message>
    <MessageNode>
      <MasterDataMemberAddRequest xmlns="http://AnotherNamespace">
        ...
      </MasterDataMemberAddRequest>
    </MessageNode>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageNode>
      <MasterDataMemberAddRequest xmlns="http://AnotherNamespace">
        ...
      </MasterDataMemberAddRequest>
    </MessageNode>
  </Message>
</PolledMessage>
```

Where the **MessageNode** is a node, containing the message that i want to extract. I have done that using Envelope schema with XmlReceive pipeline, and it worked well. But after that i need to write some custom values to the message context of each of that extracted messages. i've wrote a custom pipeline, that takes property name, namespace and value and writes it to the message context, but i can't figure out how to put together that disassembling and promoting properties of disassembled messages.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arsen,

The XMLReceive pipeline debatches your envelope using the XML dissembler component, and [will promote individual message properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577970.aspx) providing they are correctly marked as [context properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561059.aspx) (and assuming they are in the message!)

If you need to push custom non-message properties into each message, you could create a custom pipeline and place your pipeline component that acts on each disassembled message in the [resolve party stage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561803.aspx).

[image]

Here's a [link](http://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/a-contextpropertypromoter-custom-pipeline-component/) to a custom context property promotion component. You'll see in the example that it is placed in the validate stage - I believe validate or resolve party are both ok. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Jason! Seems cool, but I can't check if it works, because I've faced another problem. In my custom pipeline I am using Promote method to write my values to the context: 'Message.Context.Promote("name of your property", "namespace of your property schema", value);' And it gives me the following error: 'Loading property information list by namespace failed or property not found in the list.' Have you got any idea what exactly is 'Property Name' and what is 'namespace of your property schema'?

Comment: Figured it out. That namespace argument is the namespace of the property schema file itself, not the namespace of <schema> node or target namespace.